# Deploying my MVVMCross Xamarin.Android application appears to clear the application's document store

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a simple application that writes some data from the network to a database. This works absolutely fine in iOS and Windows Phone versions of the application, but the Android version is experiencing some problems.

It seems that the data stored within the application (in the /data/data/com.myapp/ directory is removed whenever I deploy the application. According to [the source code for the connection factory](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-SQLite/blob/master/Sqlite/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite.Droid/MvxDroidSQLiteConnectionFactory.cs), the data is always stored in the value returned by `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)`, which I should imagine is an application data-specific folder, similar to the iOS application documents directory.

However, everything works as expected when I just open the application and kill it from the Android task manager and re-open it without using the debugger; the data is persisted as expected then.

I have never done Android development unfortunately, but my colleagues who have worked with non-Xamarin projects are unaware of what could be causing this issue. Perhaps MVVMCross stores the data in the wrong folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an Frequently Asked Question for Xamarin.Android

In Visual Studio the setting to change is Tools|Options|Xamarin|Android Settings|Emulator/Device debugging|Preserve application data/cache on device between deploys

[image: settings]

Comment: As an aside, the community version of the plugin also lets you specify a path - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-SQLite/blob/master/Sqlite/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite/BaseClasses.cs - I hope this will be the main version moving forwards

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that didn't come up with about an hours' worth of googling. I guess I wasn't searching for the right thing. Hopefully I've added some more keywords to help someone else in the future. Thanks Stuart, not just for this but for a great framework too.

Comment: @Stuart any recommendations for what to do if that setting refuses to work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29838729/xamarin-preserve-application-data-cache-on-device-between-deploys-not-working